# Mixing surround sound via optical cable

Tags: ableton-live, 5.1, film-mixing

I have to mix music and sfx for a short animation which will play in a cinema on a Dolby 5.1 system. I need to deliver all 6 channels as separate wav files so they can encode everything to a DCP. My plan is to use the Waves 360 tools with Ableton Live 8.

I want to use the optical output on my imac and connect it to a surround receiver to monitor all 6 channels, then solo each one of them and export a separate track for each channel.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The monitoring probably won't work. The optical connection on computers is S/PDIF, not Lightpipe/ADAT. That means it will only carry two channels of audio. If you have an encoder plug-in that you can put in line between your discrete DAW tracks and the computer output, you might be able to pull it off.

Comment: Thanks Shaun! Do you know a kind of plug-in that's able to do this?

Comment: @JScholten - Neyrinck has a bunch of encoder plug-ins, as does Minnetonka (minnetonkaaudio.com). You would have to make sure you get one that will encode to a format your receiver can decode. Be warned though, these tools are not cheap.

Answer (score 0):

check out the MOTU audio interfaces. they have a TouchOSC option to control them. 
but really given that you want to then RENDER the MIX… remote cotrol of the DAW sounds a shit load more useful.